# Private connection between GKE and Compute Engine on Google Cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, firewall

- I have a compute engine instance with persistent file storage that I need outside of my GKE cluster.
- I would like to open a specific TCP port on the Compute Engine instance so that only nodes within the GKE cluster can access it.
- The Compute Engine instance and GKE cluster are in the same GCP project, network, and subnet.
- The GKE cluster is not private and I have an ingress exposing the only service I want exposed to the internet.

I've tried creating firewall rules of three different types that do not work:

- By shared service account on both Compute Engine instance and K8s nodes.
- By network tags - (yes I am using the network tags as explicitly specified on the VM instance page).
- By IP address, where I use network tag for target and private IANA IP ranges `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, and `192.168.0.0/16` for source.

The *only* thing that works is the last option but using `0.0.0.0/0` for source IP range.

I've looked at a few related questions such as:

- [Google App Engine communicate with Compute Engine over internal network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155795/google-app-engine-communicate-with-compute-engine-over-internal-network)
- [Can I launch Google Container Engine (GKE) in Private GCP network Subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156606/can-i-launch-google-container-engine-gke-in-private-gcp-network-subnet)

But I'm not looking to make my GKE cluster private and I have tried to create the firewall rules using network tags to no avail.

What am I missing or is this not possible?

Comment: How do you reach your VM? with private IP? Do you VMs have public IP? Do you have app or addon installed on GKE? Such as Istio

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere From my K8s services, I reach the compute instance via its internal IP. The Compute Engine instance has an ephemeral external IP (come to think of it, it would be sufficient to disable the ephemeral external IP)... I am not using any service mesh app, Istio or otherwise.

Comment: And you can't reach your VM from your GKE cluster right? What's the IP of the node?

Comment: Yes, I can reach my VM from the GKE cluster. The issue is making sure the external IP is closed off to the Internet.

Comment: Can you share your firewall rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this, fairly certain I tried something similar a couple months back but must have had something else misconfigured.

On the GKE cluster Details page, there is a pod address range. Setting the firewall source range to GKE pod address range gave me the the desired outcome.

[image]

Comment: There's an option to specify a source service account (In this case the SA attached to the nodes) in the firewall rule instead of Pod IP range, just for an idea.

Comment: I couldn't make the source service account work.  If i ssh to the GKE node VM it works, but from the pod it doesn't